# Macbook Terminal Command Password

Tags: mysql, sql, terminal

I downloaded Mysql (MacBook).

I am trying to connect to the Mysql server that is running using the MacBook terminal.

I typed in `mysql -u root -p` and it is asking me to enter a password.

However, it is not allowing me to type in a password. How do I enter in my password?

Comment: Downloaded it from where? Different distributions come with different default passwords, some make you pick one, and others leave it blank. Does `mysql -u root` work? When you say it "is not allowing me to type in a password", do you mean that you don't *see* the password when you type?

Comment: I downloaded it from dev.mysql.com. I attempted what you suggested and it did not work. I am not able to type in my password at all. As I type, nothing is happening in the terminal.

Comment: That's normal for Terminal password prompts. Type your password, hit enter. If your password doesn't work, follow the steps at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html.

Comment: This has worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike browsers, the Terminal does not show `******` as you type a password. It just stays blank. Totally normal, just type the password and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

1.Open terminal using spotlight by pressing cmd+space

2.Type terminal tap terminal to open application

3.Type cmd: sudo mysql -u root -p

4.Enter your password

NOTE : Due to security reasons you password wont be visible to you but it has be entered in system